# storm - How to check if a topology is idle or running?

Tags: apache-storm

That can be met checking if a determined bolt is processing, if the bolt have any tuples in the queue to be inserted yet or something like that.
What I want, in resume, is know, in any way, if a topology has done it's work yet or no.
I know it sounds contradictory, since a topology should never have the work done, but I'm using it to do tests and in the beginning I have not a non-stop stream of data, but a finite amount of data.

Answer (score 2):

To check the running topologies and their statuses you can run:

```
{dir/to/storm}/bin/storm list
```

You can also navigate to the running storm UI and check topologies/logs from there.

If you want to check if the work has been performed on a tuple then you can add your own logging. I have added some logic to print out how many tuples are processed each second which I find useful.

Answer (score 0):

U can check it from the storm UI which I think is the most easiest way.